# Resizing a QPixmap inside a QLabel according to the Window

Tags: c++, qt

In my window class, inheriting of QMainWindow, I have a QLabel containing a QPixmap, updated every 20ms.

I want the QLabel, and the QPixmap inside it, to be resized according to the resizing of the window.

I want this Central Widget to take as much space as neccessary but also to be able to resize it down. Even smalled than the original size. But always keeping the ratio.

The actual code :

```
// in the window constructor
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
this->resize(500, 300);

this->setCentralWidget(this->label);

// in the updating function
QPixmap output;
output = output.fromImage(Mat2QImage(theImage));
this->label->setPixmap(output);
```

Now I've tried with :

```
output.scaled(this->label->x(), this->label->y(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio)
```

but it doesn't work ...
How can I do that ?

EDIT : I'm using Qt 5.3

Answer (score 2):

`QPixmap::scaled` is const. Next code doesn't work:

```
// in the window constructor
this->setCentralWidget(this->label);

// in the updating function
QPixmap output;
output = output.fromImage(Mat2QImage(theImage));
output.scaled( this->label->x(), this->label->y(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio );
this->label->setPixmap(output);
```

Because output doesn't change. Maybe you need something like this:

```
// in the window constructor
this->setCentralWidget(this->label);

// in the updating function
QPixmap output;
output = output.fromImage(Mat2QImage(theImage));
output = output.scaled( this->label->x(), this->label->y(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio );
this->label->setPixmap(output);
```

Comment: Nop, in the first on, the image show, in the second, it doesn't.

Comment: That code must be executed when Dialog is already shown. If you execute that code before, the label size can be zero.

Comment: By Dialog you mean QMainWindow ?
If so, the main window is shown from the beginning to the end of the application.

Comment: Copy the code into a QPushButton clicked slot... then press the button and check if image is scaled or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try puting your QLabel inside a Layout.
    
    `hl = new QHBoxLayout;
    hl->addWidget(label);
    centralWidget()->setLayout(hl);`

check this out: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

Comment: It doesn't work, nothing appears after that. And I can't set the layout as a CentralWidget.

Comment: did you call the setLayout() method?

Comment: Yes I did, but event by adding the label in the layout, the feed was nowhere.

Comment: Done ! You can check my original post. That's all I got, I won't copy paste the entirety of my code because the rest isn't relevant to the question.